# I want to create an automatic counter in JavaScript. I have code something but I cannot stop that at a certain number can anyone help me this

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to create a JavaScript counter for my website and I am unable to stop that counter at a certain count below is the code attached and the output image as well. Please help me with this.

**Here's the Code**

```
<body onload="incrementCount(0)">
<div class="main_container" id="id_main_container">
  <div class="container_inner" id="display_div_id">
  </div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
var counter_list = [0,0,0,0,0];
var str_counter_0 = counter_list[0];
var str_counter_1 = counter_list[1];
var str_counter_2 = counter_list[2];
var str_counter_3 = counter_list[3];
var str_counter_4 = counter_list[4];
var display_str = "";
var display_div = document.getElementById("display_div_id");

function incrementCount(current_count){
  setInterval(function(){
  // clear count
  while (display_div.hasChildNodes()) {
      display_div.removeChild(display_div.lastChild);
  }
  str_counter_0++;
  if (str_counter_0 > 9) {
    str_counter_0 = 0; // reset count
    str_counter_1++;    // increase next count
  }
  if(str_counter_1>9){
    str_counter_1 = 0;
    str_counter_2++;
  }
  if(str_counter_2>9){
    str_counter_2 = 0;
    str_counter_3++;
  }
  if(str_counter_3>9){
    str_counter_3 = 0;
    str_counter_4++;
  }

  display_str = str_counter_4.toString() + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + str_counter_3.toString() + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + str_counter_2.toString() + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + str_counter_1.toString() + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + str_counter_0.toString();
  for (var  i = 0; i < display_str.length; i++) {
    var new_span = document.createElement('span');
    new_span.className = 'num_tiles';
    new_span.innerText = display_str[i];
    display_div.appendChild(new_span);
   if(display_str[i] == 0 + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + 0 + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + 1 + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + 0 + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + 0 ){
        str_counter_0 = 0;
        str_counter_1 = 0;
        str_counter_2 = 0;
        str_counter_3 = 0;
        }
    }
},0200);


} 
</script>
```

**The Output should Look like this**

[image]

Comment: Would you be open to other suggestions around how to approach this problem with JavaScript or is there a reason for having this particular approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean you want stop counter at a certain number.like below stop at 50?

```html
<body onload="incrementCount(50)">
    <div class="main_container" id="id_main_container">
      <div class="container_inner" id="display_div_id">
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
    
<script>
var counter = 0;
var display_str = "";
var display_div = document.getElementById("display_div_id");

function incrementCount(stop_count){
    const interval = setInterval(function(){
        while (display_div.hasChildNodes()) {
            display_div.removeChild(display_div.lastChild);
        }
        counter++
        if(counter>=stop_count){
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
        const counter_str = String(counter).padStart(5,'0')
        
        display_str = counter_str[0] + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + counter_str[1] + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + counter_str[2] + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + counter_str[3] + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + counter_str[4];
        for (var  i = 0; i < display_str.length; i++) {
            var new_span = document.createElement('span');
            new_span.className = 'num_tiles';
            new_span.innerText = display_str[i];
            display_div.appendChild(new_span);
            if(display_str[i] == 0 + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + 0 + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + 1 + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + 0 + '\xa0 \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0  \xa0' + 0 ){
                counter = 0
            }
        }
    },0200);

} 
</script>
```